# Formula to calculate time frames

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I created a worksheet where there are two dates:

1. `AppDate`
2. `ActionDate`

I need to calculate a new `ActionDate` that is 30 days after the earlier of the `AppDate` or `ActionDate` that is input.

For example, I have an `AppDate` of 10/30/13 and an `ActionDate` of 11/1/13.  I need to calculate off of the 10/30/13 date to create the new action date (25 days out) and the 30 days from date.

The first app and action dates may be the same or may be different.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If the two dates are in cells `A1` and `B1`, use the following formula - `=MIN(A1,B1)+30`

Comment: @LisaBullerman, Welcome to StackOverflow! Users here are encouraged  mark as accepted the response which best answers their question, for this and any other question you might ask here. Find out more: [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/209031)

Answer (score 0):

As Tim has pointed out, the [`MIN(number1,number2,...)`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/min-HP005209176.aspx) function in excel works perfectly fine on dates in order to determine the earlier date.  Also, here's some more info on [adding days](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/add-dates-HP003056112.aspx).

So you can use something like this:

```
=MIN(A2:B2)+30
```

Which should like this:

[image: demo]